# invalid item 'jasmin' and heros in the dependencies list For soot

Tags: java, intellij-idea, soot

I want to build soot with intellj so I follow the instruction of "[Building Soot with IntelliJ IDEA](https://github.com/Sable/soot/wiki/Building-Soot-with-IntelliJ-IDEA)" in github. after I done step 5 I should resolve jasmine and heros dependency problem but I have this condition in dialogue box
[image]

and I see in problem tab these errors:
"Module soot : invalid item 'jasmin' in the dependencies list"
and "Module soot : invalid item 'heros' in the dependencies list"
How I can fix it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't use IntelliJ but does it help to add this project?
https://github.com/Sable/jasmin/

And Heros would be available here:
https://github.com/Sable/heros

Comment: I added jasmine.jar and heros.jar and delete old dependencies and it works. thanks